# Dragdealer not getting initialized

Tags: javascript, plugins, dragdealer-js

html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div id="demo-simple-slider" class="dragdealer">
        <div class="handle red-bar">
            <p><input id="values" onchange="alert();" type="text"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$( "#exampleModal1" ).on('shown', function(){
    //Dragdealer
    //Product condition
    var main_width = $('#demo-simple-slider').outerWidth();

    new Dragdealer('demo-simple-slider', {
        animationCallback: function(x, y) {
            dragged_handle();
            $('#demo-simple-slider #values').val((x * 7).toFixed(1));
            var x = $('#demo-simple-slider #values').val();
        },

    });

    //Function to set Handle position
    function dragged_handle(){
        var left_off_container = $('#demo-simple-slider').offset().left;
        var left_off = $('#demo-simple-slider .handle').offset().left;
        var width_circle = ((left_off - left_off_container) + 10);
        $('#demo-simple-slider .sado-div').width(width_circle);
    }
});
```

I have previously used this plugin and it worked perfectly. So i used the same code that is shown above but for some reason the handle does not move. There are no errors in console that is the reason why i cannot find the problem.

Comment: Is the tag with the corresponding id existent when the code runs? Check it by running console.log(document.getElementById('demo-simple-slider')); just before you initialize Dragdealer. What is the result?

Comment: @LajosArpad i get the element in console when i do console.log(document.getElementById('demo-simple-slider'));

Comment: Looks fine to me [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5evcagx/).

Comment: What happens if you remove dragdealer class from the attributes of the tag? I think it may be a signal that dragdealer was already initialized.

Comment: @LajosArpad i tried removing the class still it does not help.

Comment: @emineminems I have no idea why my handle does not move.

Just now it was working but when i reload again the same problem

Comment: @Raj Perhaps you can give us more context (i.e. include more relevant code)

Comment: @emineminems can it be bacause i have the code in a bootstrap modal?

Comment: @Raj maybe. please edit the question and put more code so we can reproduce the issue

Comment: @emineminems i have edited the code. It seems the bootstrap modal was the reason it was not getting initialized. But now even when i have written the code when the modal is shown its not working.

Comment: @emineminems thanks for all the help i finally got it working. I wrote a click function after opening the form that initializes dragdealer. Also i created a var to check if it was previously initialized to avoid reinitializing it multiple times.

Comment: @Raj you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Just change your Bootstrap modal shown handler
 from `$( "#exampleModal1" ).on('shown', function(){ ... })`
to `$( "#exampleModal1" ).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){ ... })` 
See [Bootstrap Modal Events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

You are also going to want to wrap the handler in `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`

Lastly, do not forget to include the relevant stylesheets and scripts. Hope this helps

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#exampleModal1").on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
//Dragdealer
//Product condition

var main_width = $('#demo-simple-slider').outerWidth();

new Dragdealer('demo-simple-slider', {
  animationCallback: function(x, y) {
    dragged_handle();
    $('#demo-simple-slider #values').val((x * 7).toFixed(1));
    var x = $('#demo-simple-slider #values').val();
  },

});

//Function to set Handle position
function dragged_handle() {
  var left_off_container = $('#demo-simple-slider').offset().left;
  var left_off = $('#demo-simple-slider .handle').offset().left;
  var width_circle = ((left_off - left_off_container) + 10);
  $('#demo-simple-slider .sado-div').width(width_circle);
}
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dragdealer@0.10.0/src/dragdealer.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dragdealer@0.10.0/src/dragdealer.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal1">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div id="demo-simple-slider" class="dragdealer">
    <div class="handle red-bar">
      <p><input id="values" onchange="alert();" type="text"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried but this was not working so i wrote an onclick function inside the modal to initialize the plugin. Anyways thanks a lot :)